# How to add form parameters to a NSURLSessionUploadTask

Tags: ios, objective-c, foundation, nsurlsession

I need to upload a file to a server and the request has to specify some form parameters. How can I do this with the NSURLSessionUploadTask? In other words, how can I send a multipart POST request.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

When using `NSURLSessionUploadTask`, you don't call `setHTTPBody` on the `NSMutableURLRequest` (like we used to do with `NSURLConnection`), but rather you include this in the `NSData` or file passed to the `NSURLSession` method, `uploadTaskWithRequest` (or in the stream we supply for `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest`).

In terms of creating the body of the request, itself, you have to do this yourself. Obviously, a framework like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) can greatly simplify this process.

Comment: so basically I have to build the body myself, right ?

Comment: @Jan Yep, unless you use a framework like AFNetworking.

Comment: @Rob I am uploading files using a background session, which only support from file, I also need to send a multiform request, my NSURLRequest right now includes the multi form part and the NSData of the file a photo in this case, and I got it to work using NSURLSessionDownloadTask in the background, which is a work around, but doesn't seem right at all. I see you mention, that we can include the data in the file itself, how would I go about doing this?, would it be a file containing the multi form request and the nsdata of the image?, any links or documentation on how to do this would be great.

Comment: @Rob Note that i can actually use use an uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest in the background but only on iOS 8 and it works just fine, but it fails on iOS 7 with the assertion on background upload only supported from a file. I still have to support 7 unfortunately.

Comment: @OscarGomez Then put your your full upload request body in a separate file and upload that.

Comment: @Rob Thanks Rob I though about doing that, shortly after writing this, and it worked! thank you, it is an inconvenience that I have to save it to a file first though.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pyke369/PKMultipartInputStream

This library can generate the multipart request pretty well.